# Are there different types of sage modes?

Tags: naruto

Why are some sage modes evil and make the user violent like Jugo's clan and Kabuto's sage mode? And why is Naruto's sage mode "less dark" ? Are there different types of sage modes? They all use natural energy so shouldnt they be the same?

Comment: Yes there is different types of sage modes. I think there's one for different animals.

Comment: but..dont they all use natural energy? Then why the difference..?

Comment: They all use natural energy, yes. I think the animals they represent is the only difference, and the powers they get. Now remember, I'm saying "I think" as in it's my theories, you could say..

Comment: oh..but i still dont get why using natural energy transforms you into different creatures...how could using the same thing transform you to different creatures depending on where you learned them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are different types of sage mode, depending on summons. But I think you're asking if there is like an evil sage mode. Well...to put in similarity terms: No. Sage mode is basically the opposite of when Naruto loses control over his tailed beast. You have to be in perfect control, and if you're not, you become literally an animal or stone, not some rampaging demon. Now this doesn't mean that Sage mode is only reserved for good guys. It really depends on the summon. If the summon you use is evil and wants to teach you sage mode for your evil reasons, by all means you can do that. Like Kabuto....and Orochimaru....

Comment: It could be argued that Jugo enters sage mode and it turns him into an insane murderer. He is somewhat unable to control his natural ability to absorb nature energy, and we all know enough nature energy transforms people.